# Вывод данных из 2 моделей в один view yii2

Tags: yii2, mvc

Есть 2 таблицы - клиенты и заказы. Связь один к многим. Как в один view вывести инфу о клиенте из модели "клиенты", а снизу список всех его заказов используя модель "заказы"?  Начитал что как то через виджет это реализуют, правильно ли это? И как это реализовать?

Comment: Вы передаёте во view модель, у которой есть relation, вот и обращайтесь к нему. Как это делать, ручками через чей-то виджет или еще как, зависит только от вашей фантазии и требований

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В своем контролере Вы получаете модель клиента:

```
$client = ClientActiveRecord::findById($_GET['client_id']);
```

Передаете этого $client во вьюшку.

А во вьюшке после вывода инфо о клиенте пишете так:

```
foreach($client->getOrders() as $order) {
    // вызываете под вьюшку для заказа либо 
    var_dump($order);
}
```

Либо вызываете самописный виджет:

```
OrdersWidget::run($client->getOrders());
```

Вариантов масса.